# Error installing DocPad 6.53 on Windows 7

Tags: docpad

When I try to install DocPad using the following command

```
npm install -g docpad@6.53
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: reduce@'RedVentures/reduce#346d59'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.2"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "docpad@6.53.4
"
npm ERR! cwd D:\!Docpad
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
```

- OS: Windows 7
- NodeJs: v0.10.20
- NPM: 1.3.11

Any idea what could be wrong? How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing [Git](http://git-scm.com/download/win) and adding it to the Path solved the issue:

[image]

More info can be found [there](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/675).